# Serving static files with CherryPy ignores mount point?

Tags: python, configuration, cherrypy, static-files

I'm trying to server static content for my CherryPy app, and everything works fine when the app is mounted at the root:

```
cherrypy.quickstart(root=Controller(), config="../app.conf")
```

with the following app.conf:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.root: os.path.abspath("../public")
tools.encode.on: False
tools.gzip.on: True
tools.gzip.mime_types: ['text/html', 'text/plain', 'application/json',    'text/javascript', 'application/javascript']
tools.staticdir.debug: True

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'js'

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'css'

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'images'
```

However, when replacing the cherrypy.quickstart call with the following (note the script_name):

```
app1 = cherrypy.tree.mount(root=Controller(), config="../app.conf", script_name="/myapp")
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

the dynamic urls (i.e. the cherrypy "route" methods) are correctly redirected to /myapp/[method name] but static files are still server from the root URL. How can I get the static file serving to automatically use the new mount point? Can I use the new mount point while still referring to the relative static content folder filepaths?

Comment: you must map app specific static resources manually.it's independent from app tree.

Comment: I had just answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018087/internal-server-error-returning-no-useful-information-in-cherrypy/18338006#18338006

And showed some of my work when I answered my own question here dealing with config files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213197/integrating-css-and-cherrypy-how-to-fix-the-404-not-found-error/18221011#18221011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.root: os.path.abspath("public/")
tools.encode.on: False
tools.gzip.on: True
tools.gzip.mime_types: ['text/html', 'text/plain', 'application/json', 'text/javascript', 'application/javascript']

[/static]
tools.etags.on: True
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: "public"

[/js]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'js'

[/css]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'css'

[/images]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'images'
```